# Centering text vertically

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm working on a site that is going to look like this:

[image: Site]

I'm struggling to align this text within the center of the box like this:

[image: Box]

This is what I have so far:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Trend Sans 004'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/Trend Sans W00 Four.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Utopia Regular'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/utopia-regular.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Trend Sans 001'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/Trend Sans W00 One.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}




/*
* Skeleton V2.0.4
* Copyright 2014, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 12/29/2014
*/


/* Table of contents
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
- Grid
- Base Styles
- Typography
- Links
- Buttons
- Forms
- Lists
- Code
- Tables
- Spacing
- Utilities
- Clearing
- Media Queries
*/


/* Grid
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.column,
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/* For devices larger than 400px */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0; }
}

/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%; }
  .column,
  .columns {
    margin-left: 4%; }
  .column:first-child,
  .columns:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    }

  .one.column,
  .one.columns                    { width: 4.66666666667%; }
  .two.columns                    { width: 13.3333333333%; }
  .three.columns                  { width: 22%;            }
  .four.columns                   { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .five.columns                   { width: 39.3333333333%; }
  .six.columns                    { width: 48%;            }
  .seven.columns                  { width: 56.6666666667%; }
  .eight.columns                  { width: 65.3333333333%; }
  .nine.columns                   { width: 74.0%;          }
  .ten.columns                    { width: 82.6666666667%; }
  .eleven.columns                 { width: 91.3333333333%; }
  .twelve.columns                 { width: 100%; margin-left: 0; }

  .one-third.column               { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .two-thirds.column              { width: 65.3333333333%; }

  .one-half.column                { width: 48%; }

  /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column,
  .offset-by-one.columns          { margin-left: 8.66666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two.column,
  .offset-by-two.columns          { margin-left: 17.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-three.column,
  .offset-by-three.columns        { margin-left: 26%;            }
  .offset-by-four.column,
  .offset-by-four.columns         { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-five.column,
  .offset-by-five.columns         { margin-left: 43.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-six.column,
  .offset-by-six.columns          { margin-left: 52%;            }
  .offset-by-seven.column,
  .offset-by-seven.columns        { margin-left: 60.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eight.column,
  .offset-by-eight.columns        { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-nine.column,
  .offset-by-nine.columns         { margin-left: 78.0%;          }
  .offset-by-ten.column,
  .offset-by-ten.columns          { margin-left: 86.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eleven.column,
  .offset-by-eleven.columns       { margin-left: 95.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-third.column,
  .offset-by-one-third.columns    { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two-thirds.column,
  .offset-by-two-thirds.columns   { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-half.column,
  .offset-by-one-half.columns     { margin-left: 52%; }

}


/* Base Styles
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* NOTE
html is set to 62.5% so that all the REM measurements throughout Skeleton
are based on 10px sizing. So basically 1.5rem = 15px :) */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }
body {
background-color:#C8D7DC;
}


/* Typography
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300; }
h1 { font-size: 4.0rem; line-height: 1.2;  letter-spacing: -.1rem;}
h2 { font-size: 3.6rem; line-height: 1.25; letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h3 { font-size: 3.0rem; line-height: 1.3;  letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h4 { font-size: 2.4rem; line-height: 1.35; letter-spacing: -.08rem; }
h5 { font-size: 1.8rem; line-height: 1.5;  letter-spacing: -.05rem; }
h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 1.6;  letter-spacing: 0; }

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  h1 { font-size: 5.0rem; }
  h2 { font-size: 4.2rem; }
  h3 { font-size: 3.6rem; }
  h4 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
  h5 { font-size: 2.4rem; }
  h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; }
}

p {
  margin-top: 0; }





/* Buttons
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.button:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
.button:focus,
button:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-color: #888;
  outline: 0; }
.button.button-primary,
button.button-primary,
input[type="submit"].button-primary,
input[type="reset"].button-primary,
input[type="button"].button-primary {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #33C3F0;
  border-color: #33C3F0; }
.button.button-primary:hover,
button.button-primary:hover,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="button"].button-primary:hover,
.button.button-primary:focus,
button.button-primary:focus,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="button"].button-primary:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1EAEDB;
  border-color: #1EAEDB; }


/* Forms
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea,
select {
  height: 38px;
  padding: 6px 10px; /* The 6px vertically centers text on FF, ignored by Webkit */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
/* Removes awkward default styles on some inputs for iOS */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none; }
textarea {
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px; }
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #33C3F0;
  outline: 0; }
label,
legend {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 600; }
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0; }
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline; }
label > .label-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  font-weight: normal; }


/* Lists
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
ul {
  list-style: circle inside; }
ol {
  list-style: decimal inside; }
ol, ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0; }
ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3rem;
  font-size: 90%; }
li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }


/* Code
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
code {
  padding: .2rem .5rem;
  margin: 0 .2rem;
  font-size: 90%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  border-radius: 4px; }
pre > code {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: pre; }


/* Tables
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
th,
td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0; }
th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0; }


/* Spacing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
button,
.button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }
input,
textarea,
select,
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem; }
pre,
blockquote,
dl,
figure,
table,
p,
ul,
ol,
form {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem; }


/* Utilities
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.u-full-width {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-max-full-width {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-pull-right {
  float: right; }
.u-pull-left {
  float: left; }


/* Misc
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */



/* Clearing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

/* Self Clearing Goodness */
.container:after,
.row:after,
.u-cf {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both; }


/* Media Queries
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/*
Note: The best way to structure the use of media queries is to create the queries
near the relevant code. For example, if you wanted to change the styles for buttons
on small devices, paste the mobile query code up in the buttons section and style it
there.
*/


/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}

/* Larger than phablet (also point when grid becomes active) */
@media (min-width: 550px) {}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}


/* Header
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#header {
font-size:10vw;
margin-top:5%;
text-align: center;
font-family:'Trend Sans 004';
color: #806239;
}


/* Row 1
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row1 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
color:#806239;
border: 2px #806239 solid;
margin-top:2%;
padding:1%;
font-size:2vw;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#row1 a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}


#row1 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#row1 li {
    display: inline;
    
}

#row1 li {
    display: inline;
}

#kjn {
padding-right:25%;
padding-left:25%;
}



/* Row 3
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row3 {
background-color:#806239;
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
margin-top:2%;
text-align:center;
color: white;
padding:5%;
}

#mail {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
letter-spacing:2px;
font-size:1.8vw;
}

#first {
margin-top:-5%;
font-size:1.5vw;
letter-spacing:.4px;
}





/* Box Row
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#boxRow {
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
margin-top:2%;
}

#boxRowImg1 {
background-image: url("images/interior.png");
background-color:grey;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
width: 48%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 48%;
}

#boxRowImg2 {
background-image: url("images/bread.jpg");
background-color:grey;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
width: 48%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 48%;
}

#boxRowTxt {
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px #806239 inset;
width: 48%;
color:#163764;
position:static;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 48%;
font-size:1.7vw;
}

#boxRowTxt h5 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';

font-size:3vw;
}

#boxRowTxt p {
margin-top:-10px;
}

#boxRowTxt hr {
height:1px;
width:40%;
background-color:#163764;
border-width:0px;

}

#aa {
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
padding-left:10%;
padding-right:10%;
}



/* hr
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

hr {
height:1px;
width:100%;
background-color:#806239;
border-width:0px;
margin-top:2%;
}

/* Row 6
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row6 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
margin-top:.5%;
margin-bottom:1.5%;
font-size:1.3vw;
color:#806239;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cupid's Cafe & Bakery</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Cupid's Cafe & Bakery">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  

  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Cupids.css">
  

  <!-- Favicon
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="header">
  Cupid's
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row1">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a id="kjn" href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row" id="boxRow">
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowImg1" >
  </div>
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowTxt" >
  <div id="aa">
  <h5>The Bakery</h5></br>
  <p>Like a home away from home, our secluded cafe is the perfect place to relax, work, or settle in with a good book. Make sure to try one of our delicious lunch options or expertly brewed hot drinks. </p>
  <hr align="left" >
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row3">
  <p id="mail">Join our mailing list</p>
  <p id="first">Be the first to know about special promotions, and events!</p>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
    <div class="row" id="boxRow">
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowImg2" >
  </div>
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowTxt" >
  <div id="aa">
   <h5>The Bakery</h5></br>
  <p>In addition to coffee, we also offer a large selection of baked goods. Ranging from pastry assorments to artisan bread, all of out products are freshly baked from scratch each morning.</p>
  
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row5">
  <hr width="100%">
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row6">
  copyright 2016, emily baker
  </div>
  </div>
  
    
  </div>

<!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I just want to make the text sit within the middle of the box. Also, the spacing between the header, paragraph, and hr changes when i resize the window, which I don't want.

Comment: Visit http://www.w3schools.com/, its useful as a reference tool, you want to use "vertical-align".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css) and a host of other similar answers found by searching SO.

Comment: @SPlatten Might I recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) instead of w3schools? See http://www.w3fools.com/ for more info.

Comment: TylerH w3fools no longer has a problem with w3schools and even recommends it, for beginners, and has done so for years.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

1) Wrap your `aa` between two containers :

```
<div id="aa-outer-container">
  <div id="aa-inner-container">
    <div id="aa">
      <h5>The Bakery</h5></br>
      <p>Like a home away from home, our secluded cafe is the perfect place to relax, work, or settle in with a good book. Make sure to try one of our delicious lunch options or expertly brewed hot drinks. </p>
      <hr align="left" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2) Add the following CSS :

```
#boxRowTxt {
    position : relative;
}

#aa-outer-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position : absolute;
    display: table;
}

#aa-inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

#aa {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#aa h5 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#aa p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
```

That should fix your problem!

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r92f7hv7/) for a demo!

Comment: It seems to be working at first but then when i'm resizing the windo, the text falls under/out of the box completely

Comment: @E.B. : Could you prepare a Fiddle that demonstrates the problem you're having? It works as expected in my Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/r92f7hv7/).

Comment: here's a picture of what happens when I make the window more narrow: http://imgur.com/HjEY11r

Comment: @E.B. : What widths are we talking about? 300px and below? Consider adding a media query for those widths -> https://jsfiddle.net/r92f7hv7/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can just add text-align:center; to the #aa div. If you only want to do this for the one box, rather than both #aa boxes, wrap another div around the box that you want to do it to and apply the style to that instead.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Trend Sans 004'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/Trend Sans W00 Four.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Utopia Regular'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/utopia-regular.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Trend Sans 001'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/Trend Sans W00 One.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}




/*
* Skeleton V2.0.4
* Copyright 2014, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 12/29/2014
*/


/* Table of contents
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
- Grid
- Base Styles
- Typography
- Links
- Buttons
- Forms
- Lists
- Code
- Tables
- Spacing
- Utilities
- Clearing
- Media Queries
*/


/* Grid
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.column,
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/* For devices larger than 400px */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0; }
}

/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%; }
  .column,
  .columns {
    margin-left: 4%; }
  .column:first-child,
  .columns:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    }

  .one.column,
  .one.columns                    { width: 4.66666666667%; }
  .two.columns                    { width: 13.3333333333%; }
  .three.columns                  { width: 22%;            }
  .four.columns                   { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .five.columns                   { width: 39.3333333333%; }
  .six.columns                    { width: 48%;            }
  .seven.columns                  { width: 56.6666666667%; }
  .eight.columns                  { width: 65.3333333333%; }
  .nine.columns                   { width: 74.0%;          }
  .ten.columns                    { width: 82.6666666667%; }
  .eleven.columns                 { width: 91.3333333333%; }
  .twelve.columns                 { width: 100%; margin-left: 0; }

  .one-third.column               { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .two-thirds.column              { width: 65.3333333333%; }

  .one-half.column                { width: 48%; }

  /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column,
  .offset-by-one.columns          { margin-left: 8.66666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two.column,
  .offset-by-two.columns          { margin-left: 17.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-three.column,
  .offset-by-three.columns        { margin-left: 26%;            }
  .offset-by-four.column,
  .offset-by-four.columns         { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-five.column,
  .offset-by-five.columns         { margin-left: 43.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-six.column,
  .offset-by-six.columns          { margin-left: 52%;            }
  .offset-by-seven.column,
  .offset-by-seven.columns        { margin-left: 60.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eight.column,
  .offset-by-eight.columns        { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-nine.column,
  .offset-by-nine.columns         { margin-left: 78.0%;          }
  .offset-by-ten.column,
  .offset-by-ten.columns          { margin-left: 86.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eleven.column,
  .offset-by-eleven.columns       { margin-left: 95.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-third.column,
  .offset-by-one-third.columns    { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two-thirds.column,
  .offset-by-two-thirds.columns   { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-half.column,
  .offset-by-one-half.columns     { margin-left: 52%; }

}


/* Base Styles
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* NOTE
html is set to 62.5% so that all the REM measurements throughout Skeleton
are based on 10px sizing. So basically 1.5rem = 15px :) */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }
body {
background-color:#C8D7DC;
}


/* Typography
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300; }
h1 { font-size: 4.0rem; line-height: 1.2;  letter-spacing: -.1rem;}
h2 { font-size: 3.6rem; line-height: 1.25; letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h3 { font-size: 3.0rem; line-height: 1.3;  letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h4 { font-size: 2.4rem; line-height: 1.35; letter-spacing: -.08rem; }
h5 { font-size: 1.8rem; line-height: 1.5;  letter-spacing: -.05rem; }
h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 1.6;  letter-spacing: 0; }

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  h1 { font-size: 5.0rem; }
  h2 { font-size: 4.2rem; }
  h3 { font-size: 3.6rem; }
  h4 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
  h5 { font-size: 2.4rem; }
  h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; }
}

p {
  margin-top: 0; }





/* Buttons
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.button:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
.button:focus,
button:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-color: #888;
  outline: 0; }
.button.button-primary,
button.button-primary,
input[type="submit"].button-primary,
input[type="reset"].button-primary,
input[type="button"].button-primary {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #33C3F0;
  border-color: #33C3F0; }
.button.button-primary:hover,
button.button-primary:hover,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="button"].button-primary:hover,
.button.button-primary:focus,
button.button-primary:focus,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="button"].button-primary:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1EAEDB;
  border-color: #1EAEDB; }


/* Forms
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea,
select {
  height: 38px;
  padding: 6px 10px; /* The 6px vertically centers text on FF, ignored by Webkit */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
/* Removes awkward default styles on some inputs for iOS */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none; }
textarea {
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px; }
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #33C3F0;
  outline: 0; }
label,
legend {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 600; }
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0; }
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline; }
label > .label-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  font-weight: normal; }


/* Lists
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
ul {
  list-style: circle inside; }
ol {
  list-style: decimal inside; }
ol, ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0; }
ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3rem;
  font-size: 90%; }
li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }


/* Code
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
code {
  padding: .2rem .5rem;
  margin: 0 .2rem;
  font-size: 90%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  border-radius: 4px; }
pre > code {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: pre; }


/* Tables
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
th,
td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0; }
th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0; }


/* Spacing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
button,
.button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }
input,
textarea,
select,
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem; }
pre,
blockquote,
dl,
figure,
table,
p,
ul,
ol,
form {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem; }


/* Utilities
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.u-full-width {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-max-full-width {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-pull-right {
  float: right; }
.u-pull-left {
  float: left; }


/* Misc
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */



/* Clearing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

/* Self Clearing Goodness */
.container:after,
.row:after,
.u-cf {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both; }


/* Media Queries
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/*
Note: The best way to structure the use of media queries is to create the queries
near the relevant code. For example, if you wanted to change the styles for buttons
on small devices, paste the mobile query code up in the buttons section and style it
there.
*/


/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}

/* Larger than phablet (also point when grid becomes active) */
@media (min-width: 550px) {}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}


/* Header
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#header {
font-size:10vw;
margin-top:5%;
text-align: center;
font-family:'Trend Sans 004';
color: #806239;
}


/* Row 1
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row1 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
color:#806239;
border: 2px #806239 solid;
margin-top:2%;
padding:1%;
font-size:2vw;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#row1 a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}


#row1 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#row1 li {
    display: inline;
    
}

#row1 li {
    display: inline;
}

#kjn {
padding-right:25%;
padding-left:25%;
}



/* Row 3
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row3 {
background-color:#806239;
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
margin-top:2%;
text-align:center;
color: white;
padding:5%;
}

#mail {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
letter-spacing:2px;
font-size:1.8vw;
}

#first {
margin-top:-5%;
font-size:1.5vw;
letter-spacing:.4px;
}





/* Box Row
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#boxRow {
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
margin-top:2%;
}

#boxRowImg1 {
background-image: url("images/interior.png");
background-color:grey;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
width: 48%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 48%;
}

#boxRowImg2 {
background-image: url("images/bread.jpg");
background-color:grey;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
width: 48%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 48%;
}

#boxRowTxt {
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px #806239 inset;
width: 48%;
color:#163764;
position:static;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 48%;
font-size:1.7vw;
}

#boxRowTxt h5 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';

font-size:3vw;
}

#boxRowTxt p {
margin-top:-10px;
}

#boxRowTxt hr {
height:1px;
width:40%;
background-color:#163764;
border-width:0px;

}

#aa {
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
padding-left:10%;
padding-right:10%;
}
#aa p{
    text-align: center;
}



/* hr
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

hr {
height:1px;
width:100%;
background-color:#806239;
border-width:0px;
margin-top:2%;
}

/* Row 6
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row6 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
margin-top:.5%;
margin-bottom:1.5%;
font-size:1.3vw;
color:#806239;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cupid's Cafe & Bakery</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Cupid's Cafe & Bakery">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  

  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Cupids.css">
  

  <!-- Favicon
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="header">
  Cupid's
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row1">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a id="kjn" href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row" id="boxRow">
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowImg1" >
  </div>
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowTxt" >
  <div id="aa">
  <h5>The Bakery</h5></br>
  <p>Like a home away from home, our secluded cafe is the perfect place to relax, work, or settle in with a good book. Make sure to try one of our delicious lunch options or expertly brewed hot drinks. </p>
  <hr align="left" >
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row3">
  <p id="mail">Join our mailing list</p>
  <p id="first">Be the first to know about special promotions, and events!</p>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
    <div class="row" id="boxRow">
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowImg2" >
  </div>
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowTxt" >
  <div id="aa">
   <h5>The Bakery</h5></br>
  <p>In addition to coffee, we also offer a large selection of baked goods. Ranging from pastry assorments to artisan bread, all of out products are freshly baked from scratch each morning.</p>
  
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row5">
  <hr width="100%">
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row6">
  copyright 2016, emily baker
  </div>
  </div>
  
    
  </div>

<!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the hr to stop changing vertical positions when i resize the window?

Comment: I updated my answer for you - I just used a #aa p{} selector in the css

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want this solution: https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Trend Sans 004'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/Trend Sans W00 Four.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Utopia Regular'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/utopia-regular.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Trend Sans 001'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/Trend Sans W00 One.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}




/*
* Skeleton V2.0.4
* Copyright 2014, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 12/29/2014
*/


/* Table of contents
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
- Grid
- Base Styles
- Typography
- Links
- Buttons
- Forms
- Lists
- Code
- Tables
- Spacing
- Utilities
- Clearing
- Media Queries
*/


/* Grid
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.column,
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/* For devices larger than 400px */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0; }
}

/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%; }
  .column,
  .columns {
    margin-left: 4%; }
  .column:first-child,
  .columns:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    }

  .one.column,
  .one.columns                    { width: 4.66666666667%; }
  .two.columns                    { width: 13.3333333333%; }
  .three.columns                  { width: 22%;            }
  .four.columns                   { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .five.columns                   { width: 39.3333333333%; }
  .six.columns                    { width: 48%;            }
  .seven.columns                  { width: 56.6666666667%; }
  .eight.columns                  { width: 65.3333333333%; }
  .nine.columns                   { width: 74.0%;          }
  .ten.columns                    { width: 82.6666666667%; }
  .eleven.columns                 { width: 91.3333333333%; }
  .twelve.columns                 { width: 100%; margin-left: 0; }

  .one-third.column               { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .two-thirds.column              { width: 65.3333333333%; }

  .one-half.column                { width: 48%; }

  /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column,
  .offset-by-one.columns          { margin-left: 8.66666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two.column,
  .offset-by-two.columns          { margin-left: 17.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-three.column,
  .offset-by-three.columns        { margin-left: 26%;            }
  .offset-by-four.column,
  .offset-by-four.columns         { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-five.column,
  .offset-by-five.columns         { margin-left: 43.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-six.column,
  .offset-by-six.columns          { margin-left: 52%;            }
  .offset-by-seven.column,
  .offset-by-seven.columns        { margin-left: 60.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eight.column,
  .offset-by-eight.columns        { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-nine.column,
  .offset-by-nine.columns         { margin-left: 78.0%;          }
  .offset-by-ten.column,
  .offset-by-ten.columns          { margin-left: 86.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eleven.column,
  .offset-by-eleven.columns       { margin-left: 95.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-third.column,
  .offset-by-one-third.columns    { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two-thirds.column,
  .offset-by-two-thirds.columns   { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-half.column,
  .offset-by-one-half.columns     { margin-left: 52%; }

}


/* Base Styles
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* NOTE
html is set to 62.5% so that all the REM measurements throughout Skeleton
are based on 10px sizing. So basically 1.5rem = 15px :) */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }
body {
background-color:#C8D7DC;
}


/* Typography
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300; }
h1 { font-size: 4.0rem; line-height: 1.2;  letter-spacing: -.1rem;}
h2 { font-size: 3.6rem; line-height: 1.25; letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h3 { font-size: 3.0rem; line-height: 1.3;  letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h4 { font-size: 2.4rem; line-height: 1.35; letter-spacing: -.08rem; }
h5 { font-size: 1.8rem; line-height: 1.5;  letter-spacing: -.05rem; }
h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 1.6;  letter-spacing: 0; }

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  h1 { font-size: 5.0rem; }
  h2 { font-size: 4.2rem; }
  h3 { font-size: 3.6rem; }
  h4 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
  h5 { font-size: 2.4rem; }
  h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; }
}

p {
  margin-top: 0; }





/* Buttons
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.button:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
.button:focus,
button:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-color: #888;
  outline: 0; }
.button.button-primary,
button.button-primary,
input[type="submit"].button-primary,
input[type="reset"].button-primary,
input[type="button"].button-primary {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #33C3F0;
  border-color: #33C3F0; }
.button.button-primary:hover,
button.button-primary:hover,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="button"].button-primary:hover,
.button.button-primary:focus,
button.button-primary:focus,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="button"].button-primary:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1EAEDB;
  border-color: #1EAEDB; }


/* Forms
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea,
select {
  height: 38px;
  padding: 6px 10px; /* The 6px vertically centers text on FF, ignored by Webkit */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
/* Removes awkward default styles on some inputs for iOS */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none; }
textarea {
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px; }
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #33C3F0;
  outline: 0; }
label,
legend {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 600; }
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0; }
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline; }
label > .label-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  font-weight: normal; }


/* Lists
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
ul {
  list-style: circle inside; }
ol {
  list-style: decimal inside; }
ol, ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0; }
ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3rem;
  font-size: 90%; }
li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }


/* Code
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
code {
  padding: .2rem .5rem;
  margin: 0 .2rem;
  font-size: 90%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  border-radius: 4px; }
pre > code {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: pre; }


/* Tables
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
th,
td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0; }
th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0; }


/* Spacing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
button,
.button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }
input,
textarea,
select,
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem; }
pre,
blockquote,
dl,
figure,
table,
p,
ul,
ol,
form {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem; }


/* Utilities
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.u-full-width {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-max-full-width {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-pull-right {
  float: right; }
.u-pull-left {
  float: left; }


/* Misc
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */



/* Clearing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

/* Self Clearing Goodness */
.container:after,
.row:after,
.u-cf {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both; }


/* Media Queries
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/*
Note: The best way to structure the use of media queries is to create the queries
near the relevant code. For example, if you wanted to change the styles for buttons
on small devices, paste the mobile query code up in the buttons section and style it
there.
*/


/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}

/* Larger than phablet (also point when grid becomes active) */
@media (min-width: 550px) {}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}


/* Header
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#header {
font-size:10vw;
margin-top:5%;
text-align: center;
font-family:'Trend Sans 004';
color: #806239;
}


/* Row 1
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row1 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
color:#806239;
border: 2px #806239 solid;
margin-top:2%;
padding:1%;
font-size:2vw;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#row1 a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}


#row1 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#row1 li {
    display: inline;
    
}

#row1 li {
    display: inline;
}

#kjn {
padding-right:25%;
padding-left:25%;
}



/* Row 3
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row3 {
background-color:#806239;
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
margin-top:2%;
text-align:center;
color: white;
padding:5%;
}

#mail {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
letter-spacing:2px;
font-size:1.8vw;
}

#first {
margin-top:-5%;
font-size:1.5vw;
letter-spacing:.4px;
}





/* Box Row
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#boxRow {
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
margin-top:2%;
}

#boxRowImg1 {
background-image: url("images/interior.png");
background-color:grey;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
width: 48%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 48%;
}

#boxRowImg2 {
background-image: url("images/bread.jpg");
background-color:grey;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
width: 48%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 48%;
}

#boxRowTxt {
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px #806239 inset;
width: 48%;
color:#163764;
position:relative;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 48%;
font-size:1.7vw;
}

#boxRowTxt h5 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';

font-size:3vw;
}

#boxRowTxt p {
margin-top:-10px;
}

#boxRowTxt hr {
height:1px;
width:40%;
background-color:#163764;
border-width:0px;

}

#aa {
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
padding-left:10%;
padding-right:10%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}



/* hr
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

hr {
height:1px;
width:100%;
background-color:#806239;
border-width:0px;
margin-top:2%;
}

/* Row 6
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row6 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
margin-top:.5%;
margin-bottom:1.5%;
font-size:1.3vw;
color:#806239;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cupid's Cafe & Bakery</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Cupid's Cafe & Bakery">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  

  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Cupids.css">
  

  <!-- Favicon
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="header">
  Cupid's
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row1">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a id="kjn" href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row" id="boxRow">
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowImg1" >
  </div>
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowTxt" >
  <div id="aa">
  <h5>The Bakery</h5></br>
  <p>Like a home away from home, our secluded cafe is the perfect place to relax, work, or settle in with a good book. Make sure to try one of our delicious lunch options or expertly brewed hot drinks. </p>
  <hr align="left" >
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row3">
  <p id="mail">Join our mailing list</p>
  <p id="first">Be the first to know about special promotions, and events!</p>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
    <div class="row" id="boxRow">
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowImg2" >
  </div>
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowTxt" >
  <div id="aa">
   <h5>The Bakery</h5></br>
  <p>In addition to coffee, we also offer a large selection of baked goods. Ranging from pastry assorments to artisan bread, all of out products are freshly baked from scratch each morning.</p>
  
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row5">
  <hr width="100%">
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row6">
  copyright 2016, emily baker
  </div>
  </div>
  
    
  </div>

<!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using padding-top and padding-bottom in your #boxRowTxt.
I have commented out a couple lines and added those, if you need more space just be sure to change them both to the same number to keep the content centred.

```
#boxRowTxt {
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px #806239 inset;
width: 48%;
color:#163764;
position:static;
/*height: 0;*/
/*padding-bottom: 48%;*/
    /*Keep the padding on top and bottom the same*/
    padding-bottom: 4%;
    padding-top: 4%;

font-size:1.7vw;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers you must support, flexbox is a great tool for this!

```
<div id="aa">
  <h5>The Bakery</h5>
  <p>Like a home away from home, our secluded cafe is the perfect place to relax, work, or settle in with a good book. Make sure to try one of our delicious lunch options or expertly brewed hot drinks. </p>
  <hr align="left">
</div>
```

Add the following to the `#aa` rule (which you could consider changing to a class)

```
#aa {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}
```